# How to extract files from corrupted svn revisions files ("myproject\db\revs\0" directory)

Tags: svn

I have some SVN files which restored from corrupted HDD and as a consequence corrupted SVN.

Is it possible to extract files from SVN revisions database files directly?

E.g. I have "MyProject\db\revs\0" and I see in this directory files with  commits "0", "2", "3", "4", ..., "7" and these files have about the same size which had lost documents.
I have only this directory ("MyProject\db\revs\0").

This is very old SVN (1.6.6). Do not need any logs or other info. I need only the most recent version of a file as possible (I am sure that most of these revision files are damaged, too).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to recover this repository in case there are missing revisions and this repository had less than 1000 revisions. Revisions don't contain files, they contain changes. Therefore, to construct a file as it was in revision X, it is required to have all the revisions where this files was changed.

Search for repository backup (if you made one) or local working copies on user machines.

Don't forget to backup in future.

Comment: Sure I always backup using svnadmin+batch files. I recovered HDD for my friend ;-) I just discovered structure of db files and see that there is really some delta between data. But thank you for info for confidence.

Comment: @AlexanderSymonenko so what about getting this dump file and loading into new repository?